indefinite article [a Lifeguard Certificate] and [a First-Aid Diploma]
I have made up the sentences below.
(1a) I will be taking a few training courses in three weeks. Upon completing them, I will receive a Lifeguard Certificate and a First-Aid Diploma.
(1b) I will be taking a few training courses in three weeks. Upon completing them, I will receive a Lifeguard Certificate and First-Aid Diploma.
Do I have to use "a" twice?

If you do not use a second article, the possibility arises that the training course might issue a "Lifeguard and First Aid Training Certificate." If the audience understands that such a certificate either does or does not exist, there is no issue, but uncertainty on the matter will cause the reader a certain amount of uncertainty, which you probably don't want.

The second article a is optional.
We use small letters if the certificate and the diploma are not proper nouns:
I will receive a lifeguard certificate and (a) first-aid diploma.
Edit
There should be no confusion on the number of awards as the two  are clearly differentiated as certificate and diploma.
